# How do I produce a plot in landscape [rotated by 90 degrees] orientation in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

The following knitr code give me the plot below -- how do I plot it in a landscape orientation?

````
```{r}
rm(list=ls())
library(tree)
set.seed(1111)
x1<-runif(100)
x2<-rnorm(100,mean=.3)
x3<-runif(100)
d1<-x1>0.5
d2<-x2>0.7
d3<-x3<0.2
y<-ifelse(d1,1,ifelse(d2,2,ifelse(d3,3,4)))
df<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)
tr<-tree(y~.,data=df)
plot(tr)
text(tr)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Looks "wider than it is tall" already to me. Isn't that what landscape means? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @MikeWise -- rotated by 90 degrees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your want a pdf/LaTeX output it is quite easy with `out.extra='angle=90'` chunk argument :

````
---
title: "Rotation test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, out.extra='angle=90'}
rm(list=ls())
library(tree)
set.seed(1111)
x1<-runif(100)
x2<-rnorm(100,mean=.3)
x3<-runif(100)
d1<-x1>0.5
d2<-x2>0.7
d3<-x3<0.2
y<-ifelse(d1,1,ifelse(d2,2,ifelse(d3,3,4)))
df<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)
tr<-tree(y~.,data=df)
plot(tr)
text(tr)
```
````

In some circumnstances it is better to keep the graph as it but to rotate just one page in landscape format within you document.
You need `pdflscape` LaTeX package for this (included for example in the texlive-latex-base package in Ubuntu as "oberdiek").

In the following example the graph is extended to occupy a full A4 page in landscape format. NB : you must specify `fig.align='center'` to make it work.

````
---
title: "Rotation test"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
      - \usepackage{pdflscape}
---

```{r}
rm(list=ls())
library(tree)
set.seed(1111)
x1<-runif(100)
x2<-rnorm(100,mean=.3)
x3<-runif(100)
d1<-x1>0.5
d2<-x2>0.7
d3<-x3<0.2
y<-ifelse(d1,1,ifelse(d2,2,ifelse(d3,3,4)))
df<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)
tr<-tree(y~.,data=df)
```

\newpage

\begin{landscape}

```{r fig.align='center', fig.width = 27/2.54, fig.height = 19/2.54}
plot(tr)
text(tr)
```
\end{landscape}

```{r}
summary(tr)
```
````

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work with R-markdown unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean ? It should work with Rmarkdown providing that you have the right LaTeX components installed

Comment: @Gilles It does work with RMarkdown but for some reason figures become a bit of an issue. Below is a clip showing this. As you can see, I've tried about 10 different ways to accomplish this. The YouTube video can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVz9qqVZgGE)

Comment: Indeed `knitr::include_graphic` function does not seem to work with landscape environement. If you are certain that your output will be a pdf latex you might directly include your graphic with LaTeX code. For example this works for me : (inserted outside any code chunk) `\begin{landscape}
\includegraphics{~/divers/images/Rlogo.jpg}
\end{landscape}`